# What is the overall-encompassing term for the "fruit-like" plant growths that we use for harvest and consumption

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, food, biology

What is a good term for plants whose parts, either as tubers, roots, or fruit/seeds are harvested and consumed? I exclude plants such as hemp and flax whose fibres are used, or, for example, poppies for opium.

Comment: Are you asking about the plants? Or the foods they produce? Or something else?

Comment: I tried to edit your question to make it more comprehensible, but I couldn't quite follow the thread. Could you [edit] this to make it less stream-of-thought-y?

Comment: You cannot reap what you've *sewn* unless you're a seamstress. You meant *sown*, which is what one does with seeds and soil rather than with needle and thread. Also please note that not all organisms with fruiting bodies are plants.

Comment: And not all that flowering and fruiting plants produce is edible.

Comment: I’m voting to close this rant because.

Comment: _Most_ of those things are (botanically) fruits. A tomato is a fruit even though in the culinary sense it is a vegetable. (BTW a cucumber belongs to the same family as melons and pumpkins - I don't know what you mean by 'sprouts'.) Carrots are root vegetables.

Comment: You yourself don't seem to agree on the definition of the category you're hoping to find a name for, so how could we? "Fruit-like plant growths" doesn't make sense: all flowering plants bear fruits, of which some are used for consumption.

Comment: *Fruits and vegetables* is the general term for any edible plant matter. It's not a single word, but not everything is a single word, even very common things.

Comment: @StuartF Produce

Comment: The question poster mentioned the word "produce" in the original question, but maybe they weren't aware that it is a potential answer. I'm not sure if they are simply looking for a hypernym for fruits and vegetables, or a hypernym that covers some other plants too. Nuts are considered a fruit also, by the way. [the original question had more deails but it was unclear also]

Comment: It is *the harvest* (in the sense *yield*), not used for the harvest (like a tractor, combine, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

**produce** *noun*

> agricultural products and especially fresh fruits and vegetables as distinguished from grain and other staple crops
>
> [*Merriam-Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/produce)

Also from *[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Produce)*'s 'Produce' article:

> **Produce** is a generalized term for many farm-produced crops, including fruits and vegetables (grains, oats, etc. are also sometimes considered *produce*). More specifically, the term produce often implies that the products are fresh and generally in the same state as where and when they were harvested.

Generally, people don't call 'wheat' produce but it could be.

Also, this is entirely anecdotal but in American English, it seems like when talking about the noun, people usually emphasize the "o", so it sounds closer to "pro-duce"; and when talking about the verb, they shorten it, so it sounds closer to "pruh-duce".

Comment: Doesn't produce include plants grown for textiles, oil, and other purposes, as well as food? In a supermarket it's restricted to fruit and veg because supermarkets don't sell e.g. raw hemp, but in an agricultural sense it seems to have a wider meaning.

Comment: Well researched and probably the best answer available.

Answer (score 1):

> What is a good term for plants whose parts, either as tubers, roots, or fruit/seeds are harvested and consumed?

They are known as **food-plants**. (Hyphen optional)

MW:

> [food plant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/food%20plant#:%7E:text=noun,provides%20food%20for%20human%20consumption) n.  : a plant (as wheat, potato, cabbage) some part of which provides food for human consumption.